# Get Element from FILES Array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, file

Ok this is probably super easy but I cant figure out how to grab items out of the following array:  The following array is from my $_FILES global.

```
array(1) {
  ["test"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(8) "204.docx"
    ["type"]=>
    string(71) "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    string(14) "/tmp/php57NIMV"
    ["error"]=>
    int(0)
    ["size"]=>
    int(13249)
  }
}
```

My goal is just to grab the data by using somthing like - echo $_FILES['test']['name'] but this does not work.  Thank you.

Comment: Show the code where you try to access that value

Comment: what is result if you var dump $_FILES['test']

Comment: That's it.  What you see above is the vardump

Answer (score 0):

sometime becouse php.ini configuration

```
max_file_size
post_max_size
```

does not sends values from the form . check your configuration

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain correctly.  The array is working correctly, all i am trying to do is echo the name of the file using the above array.

Comment: The code is above.  I am simply trying to echo out the name attribute in this array using php.  The name attribute/key is 'name' and value is 204.docx. How do i loop through or grab the name value out of this array and echo it back.  $_FILES['test']['name] was my first attempted but it is returning no value.

Comment: $_FILES['test'] also brings back empty

Comment: when you are using var_dump($_FILES) what is result ? also use top of the code     ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);